# Firebase Phone Authentication opens browser for recaptcha verification in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I have created an app with firebase phone Authentication with OTP verification, but it opens the external browser for verification of Recaptcha ,how can I disable the Recaptcha verification and stop the Authentication from opening external browser.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud **Enable** `Android Device Verification` [ADV](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com)

then add `SHA256` in your Firebase Project and update your JSON

Comment: I have done this but ,still it opens browser for recaptcha verification. How can I update JSON

Comment: FIrebase -> Project Settings  -> google-services.json

Comment: Yes, I have update json file but,still unable to solve problem opens browser for recaptcha verification.

Comment: If no luck try this FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getFirebaseAuthSettings().setAppVerificationDisabledForTesting();

Comment: Sir ,still not working I have tried this.

Comment: @AshishDawkhar Have you solved this? i'm having this problem in production and old android users cant enter my app.